# code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' } error - uncaughtException: Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

Am trying to send a request to the server to save a post. Am using Nextjs and everytime i try to send it gives me this Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

Here is my code

```
Post.js
async function uploadPost(post) {

const response = await fetch('/api/savePost', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: post,
});

if(!response.ok) {
  throw new Error('Failed to post')
}

return await response.json();
```

}

```
savePost.js

export const config = {
      api: {
      bodyParser: false,
   },
}

export default const post = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).json({
     message: 'Method not allowed'
    })
  }

  // const postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const savedPost = await prisma.post.create({
   data: req.body
  });

  res.status(200).json({message: 'Post saved successfully'})
  res.json(savedPost)
 };
```

Am using Prisma for the db
I get this error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
at NodeNextResponse.setHeader (C:\Users\user\Documents\My Received Files\js\twitter-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-http\node.js:56:19)
at DevServer.renderError (C:\Users\user\Documents\My Received Files\js\twitter-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1134:17)
at DevServer.renderError (C:\Users\user\Documents\My Received Files\js\twitter-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:493:22)
at DevServer.run (C:\Users\user\Documents\My Received Files\js\twitter-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:452:35)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\user\Documents\My Received Files\js\twitter-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:307:20) {
 code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
error - uncaughtException: Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  res.status(200).json({message: 'Post saved successfully'})  
  res.json(savedPost)
```

Here you send 2 messages back. Both with 200 code. This is what "write after send" means.

The first message set's the header and goes back.

Then after that you try to do it again, but the header is already sent.

// res.json() equals to res.status(200).json()

// You can merge res.status(200).json({message: 'Post saved successfully', savedPost: savedPost})